# Como colocar os 3 botões na parte inferior da tela?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Quero colocar 2 botões na parte inferior e 1 botão encima dos 2 botões.

Algo parecido assim: (**porem com a imagem virada de ponta para baixo**)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esses 2 botões abaixo e um botão acima dos 2 e todos esses 3 botões devem ficar na parte inferior da tela e um textview centralizado.

Segue código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ToggleButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="left " />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Right" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Segue resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem um `ToggleButton` que está na parte superior, quero que ele vá para inferior junto com os 2 botões.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu faria assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="ToggleButton" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="left " />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Right" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Coloquei os dois botões de baixo num outro LinearLayout.